# Can't perform operation because localhost does not provide a MUC (XEP-45) service

Tags: java, xmpp, ejabberd, smack

I'm trying to use multiuserchat calls with Smack plugin, but I'm receiving the following error.

```
Can't perform operation because localhost does not provide a MUC (XEP-45) service.
```

It seems like it's coming from not having mod_muc enabled in ejabberd, but I'm not sure how to activate it. I thought I was doing that in my ejabberd.yml.

Here's my ejabberd.yml mod_muc section:

```
mod_muc:
    ## host: "conference.@HOST@"
    access: muc
    access_create: muc
    access_admin: muc_admin
    history_size: 5
    max_users: 4
    default room options:
        allow_change_subj: true
        allow_private_messages: false
        allow_user_invites: true
        members_by_default: true
        public: true
        public_list: true
        persistent: false
```

Is anyone else getting the XEP-45 not provided error? How can I fix it?

Comment: Ensure you have `mod_muc` enabeld in your `ejabberd` configuration.

Comment: What parameters should I have set?

Comment: I'm not sure where to enable it.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to send MUC queries to `localhost` JID, while you should send to the JID of MUC service. Uncomment `host: "conference.@HOST@"` and use `conference.localhost` as JID for all of your MUC requests

Comment: Thanks for the response. I appreciate it. Should I put quotes around conference.localhost or no?

Comment: Put quotes and address your request to "conference.@HOST@". Means if your host is example.com then address it to conference.example.com